# How to upgrade gd library version to 2.2.5 from 2.1.1 for php 7.1?

Tags: 16.04, server, php7

How to upgrade gd library version to 2.2.5 from 2.1.1? 
I'm working on an Ubuntu server 16.04 with `php` version 7.1?

This is what I tried:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php7.1-gd
php7.1-gd is already the newest version
```

But when I look at `phpinfo()`, it 's says:

```
GD header version - 2.2.5
GD library version -2.1.1.
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: ? Some versions mix-up ? `php7.1-gd` is an Ubuntu 17.10 package !

Comment: @Michel: Try to restart you webserver  (apache, nginx, php-fpm, lighttpd ? )